# iterm itermplot tmux scroll makes plots disappear

Tags: terminal, tmux, scrolling, iterm2, matplotlib

I have a tmux session in my iTerm2 window with a single pane. When I plot something using ipython (with [itermplot](https://github.com/daleroberts/itermplot)) it appears as expected. As soon as I switch to scrolling mode ( `[` ), the plot disappears and the area where it was is now blank. Also if I switch off the scrolling mode, the plot remains invisible.

Often, I plot multiple figures at once and I would like to view the ones already out of the viewport. The question is thus:

How can I configure itermplot such that the figures survive the scrolling?